# Set the header in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rest, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to access a web based API and need to set a header for App authentication. Note that this is not a server level authentication it is at API level. I've tried every thing I could find and most of the answers on the web as well as the ones here at www.stackoverflow.com tell  me to use something like:

`[request addRequestHeader:@"username" value:@"asdf"];`

This does not work for me. The guy who built the API I'm using told me that I need to set the header as:

```
Authorization: TRUEREST username=PersonName&password=pass&apikey=dfiu6aewruif3Bismillah4Rah3anArahimiImi22MyDad
```

So I tried the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ifish-uk.co.uk/rest_users/login.json"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addRequestHeader:@"username" value:@"MyUser"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"password" value:@"MyPass"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"apikey" value:@"dfiu6aewruif3Bismillah4Rah3anArahimiImi22MyDad"];
```

But it didn't work... I even tried setting the Request type to **GET** because the developer told me I should do this:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
```

This didn't work... The API developer told me he is made this module as follow:

```
POST /rest_catches/add.json HTTP/1.1
Host: ifish-uk.co.uk
Authorization: TRUEREST     username=MyUser&password=MyPass&apikey=dfiu6aewruif3Bismillah4Rah3anArahimiImi22MyDad
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add only one header is **Authorization** no need to add separate headers for each field (use, pass, etc).

Fill it with your specific values and send.

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"TRUEREST username=PersonName&password=pass&apikey=dfiu6aewruif3Bismillah4Rah3anArahimiImi22MyDad"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```

?

Comment: No, but I thought ASIHTTPRequest was POST by default... let me try this anyway.

Comment: Tried it... still nothing :/